# Crochet A Round Disc

Tags: crocheting, amigurumi

I want to crochet a disc like object. Really, I want to make a lemon slice.
However, I can't figure out how to make the disc flat, and not rounded. I'm not sure if I need to make my decreasing/increasing more intense, or something else.

I want something like in this pic:[image]

I found [this article](https://knittingday.com/5293/crochet-lemon-free-pattern) (where I got the pic) with a pattern, but it's not readable (there's strange words mixed in). I can't find anything else related.

Does anyone have any patterns or guidance on this?

Comment: It looks like this question has the same issue as your other one that Chris H posted an answer on, and the solution would probably be the same.   It appears to point to the same article, which includes both variations on the theme.  What would you think of editing the other question to include this one, so the information is all in one place, or just marking this one as a duplicate?  It looks like a fun project, BTW.

Comment: Can you add a picture of your best attempt so far? Crocheting a disk is pretty simple in theory, but sometimes individual technique can lead to it not being perfectly flat. If you show what your attempts look like, maybe we can do some trouble-shooting. (Also, that would make this different from your other question.)

Comment: It sounds like you need to increase more slowly in the early rounds, and more frequently in the later rounds.  As you are experimenting, make sure to write down exactly what you did (as you go), so you can make a subtle correction on your next attempt. "st" = stitch.  I suggest you work with a basic How to Crochet book from the library as preparation for making a lemon slice.